# Meaning of addition in the context of boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

In Boolean algebra, the **sum** refers to the XOR operation. This makes sense to me because in GF(2) the sum is supposed to implement a sum modulo 2, which has the same truth table of the XOR logical operation.

However, in the context of *sum of products*, the **sum** refers to the logical OR operation, which is used to combine the logical ANDs representing the terms in a logical expression. Why is the sum used to represent different operations in different contexts, and how are these different meanings related to each other?

Comment: In boolean algebra, when you use the term "summing" (x+y), it is **always** ORing by default, never XORing.

Comment: So when we're talking about the Galois Field we use addition as a XOR operation, but in the context of boolean algebra the sum is always to be interpreted as an OR, am I right?

Comment: That's right. Different contexts, different default conventions. Of course $+$ is poorer than $\oplus$...